Cohomology of $\mathbb{Z}^2$ with coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}$
Let $G = \mathbb{Z}^2$ and let $\mathbb{Z}$ be the trivial module. Then, $H^{1}(\mathbb{Z}^2,\mathbb{Z}) \cong \text{Hom}(\mathbb{Z}^2, \mathbb{Z}) \cong \mathbb{Z}^2$, which is generated by projection maps onto $\mathbb{Z}$ i.e. $\pi_i : \mathbb{Z}^2 \to \mathbb{Z}, \mathbf{v} =  (v_1,v_2) \mapsto v_i$.
I would like to prove that $\pi_i^2 = 0$ with the cup product, but I'm not sure how to get the answer. Here is my attempted computation:
$$\pi^2_i(\mathbf{v}, \mathbf{w}) = (-1)^{1 \cdot 1} \pi_i(\mathbf{v}) \otimes(\mathbf{v}\pi_i(\mathbf{w}))= -v_1 \otimes w_1$$
since $\mathbb{Z}^2$ has trivial action on the trivial module. How do I see this is zero in $H^2$?
Edit: While looking at some more examples, I think I may understand why this is, so I would appreciate confirmation of whether or not my solution is correct; I have added the solution verification tag.
I think the actual value of $\pi^2_i(\mathbf{v}, \mathbf{w}) $ is not too relevant. The point is that, under the standard isomorphism $\mathbb{Z} \otimes \mathbb{Z} \cong \mathbb{Z}$ for the tensor product in the RHS, we have:
$$\pi^2_i(\mathbf{v}, \mathbf{w}) =  -v_1w_1$$
In particular, this isomorphism is invariant under the map $\rtimes$ which exchanges the factors $M \otimes N \cong N \otimes M$, where we have $M = N = \mathbb{Z}$ here. Therefore, $$\pi_i^2(\mathbf{v}, \mathbf{w}) = \rtimes(\pi_i^2(\mathbf{v},\mathbf{w}))$$
However, $\pi_i$ commutes with itself, so by the graded commutative structure on $H^{\bullet}$, we have that:
$$\pi^2_i(\mathbf{v}, \mathbf{w}) = - \rtimes(\pi_i^2(\mathbf{v},\mathbf{w})) $$
This equality is in $\mathbb{Z}$, which has no elements of order $2$ (or torsion at all), so $\pi^2_i(\mathbf{v}, \mathbf{w}) = 0$.
Please let me know if I have made any mistakes.

Why the downvote?

No, this is correct, it's a standard argument; it shows $x\cup x=0$ in most cohomology rings, of groups or spaces, where all you need is some condition about there not being any $2$-torsion in the ring or the cohomology groups - I can't quite remember.

@FShrike Thanks, glad to hear it, as I am learning this material to an extreme deadline. Does the result not also require that $x$ lies in one of the groups with odd grading?

Sorry I should have specified. I was thinking about first cohomology classes, it's not true for even cohomology classes

@FShrike No worries, I understand the reasoning. Thanks again.
